# SharePoint 2016 / Project 2016 / Office 2013 - Word/Excel documents won't open in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, project-server, office

Users with Office 2013 and Project 2016 installed are unable to open word/excel documents in SharePoint 2016 with Project Server.

Error: Sorry we can't open 'xxxxxxxx' because the server isn't responding.

Users with Office 2016 and Project 2016 installed are able to open word/excel documents in SharePoint 2016 with Project Server.

Any fixes or workarounds available?  Office 2016 compatibility pack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a supported scenario, you can use Project 2016 (`Click-to-Run`) or (`MSI`) with Office 2013 (`MSI`) on the same computer without any issue,

> For more details check: [Supported scenarios for installing different
>   versions of Office, Visio, and Project on the same computer.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/install-different-office-visio-and-project-versions-on-the-same-computer)

**So on your side, try to Make sure the following:**

- The installed Office 2013 is 64-bit.
- The Project 2016 is 64-bit.
- The office 2013 has been installed before Project 2016.
- If you have SharePoint Designer 32-bit, try to uninstall it then install SharePoint Designer 64-bit.

**Otherwise,** you have two options

1. Use Project 2013 that will work properly with `Project Server 2016` & `Office 2013`.
2. Upgrade to `Office 2016` to can use `Project 2016` as a supported scenario without any issue.

Comment: Office 2013 and Project 2016 are 64 bit, Office 2013 was installed before Project 2016, and SPD is not installed.  We will upgrade to Office 2016.  Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome @C1TonyB Please, If the above answer helped you, please don't forget to upvote and accept it as an answer!